# Add gulp-clean-css to existing gulpfile.js

Tags: css, node.js, wordpress, npm, gulp-clean-css

An associate of mine gave me a file called gulpfile.js, which had the following code in it. It watches and compiles my scss files upon save.

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
gutil      = require('gulp-util'),
browserify = require('browserify'),
uglify     = require('gulp-uglify'),
concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
changed    = require('gulp-changed'),
compass    = require('gulp-compass'),
buffer     = require('vinyl-buffer'),
source     = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var scssSources = [
        '_src/scss/**/*.scss'
    ],
    jsSources = [
        '_src/js/main.js'
    ],
    jsVendorSources = [
        '_src/js/vendor.js'
    ],
    scriptsPath = 'assets/js',
    scssPath    = 'assets/css';

var onError = function (error)
{
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(error));
    this.emit('end');
};

gulp.task('sass', function()
{
    gulp.src(scssSources)
        .pipe(changed(scssPath))
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(compass({
            style: 'expanded',
            sass: '_src/scss',
            css: scssPath,
            relative: true,
            require: ['breakpoint', 'susy']
        }))
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scssPath))
        .pipe(livereload())
});

gulp.task('js', function()
{
    return browserify(jsSources)
            .on('error', onError)
        .bundle()
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(buffer())
            .on('error', onError)
        //.pipe(uglify())
            //.on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('js-vendor', function()
{
    return browserify(jsVendorSources)
            .on('error', onError)
        .bundle()
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(buffer())
            .on('error', onError)
        //.pipe(uglify())
            //.on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function()
{
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(['_src/js/main.js', '_src/js/scripts/**/*.js'], ['js']);
    gulp.watch(['_src/js/vendor.js', '_src/js/vendor/**/*.js'], ['js-vendor']);
    gulp.watch(scssSources, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['**/*.php', '**/*.html', '**/*.twig']).on('change', function(file) { livereload.changed(file.path) })
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

However I now wish to minify my css output using the npm package "gulp-clean-css" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css). How do I add this to the existing gulpfile above?

So far I have already cd into my Wordpress theme directory and run `npm install gulp-clean-css --save-dev` - so I assume I just need to code it in somehow?

Need anymore info?

Best regards,

Oliver

Comment: In the same link you posted there are code samples of how to use this in the `gulpfile.js`. Have you tried that? It's a great way to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just told I can change style from 'expanded' to 'compressed'. Doh. Hope this helps someone anyway!